# "session has already been started...." exception in Zend Framework application

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, .htaccess, zend-auth

I get this error when trying to load a Zend Framework application:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Session_Exception' with message
>   'session has already been started by
>   session.auto-start or session_start()'
>   in
>   /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Session.php:462
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143):
>   Zend_Session::start(true)
>
> #1 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php(87):
>   Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('Zend_Auth')
>
> #2 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Auth.php(91):
>   Zend_Auth_Storage_Session->__construct()
>
> #3 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Auth.php(141):
>   Zend_Auth->getStorage()
>
> #4 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(31):
>   Zend_Auth->hasIdentity()
>
> #5 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/View.php(108):
>   include('/www/htdocs/w00...')
>
> #6 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(831):
>   Zend_View->_run('/www/htdocs/w00...')
>
> #7 /www/htdocs/w00a1ed in /www/htdocs/w00a1ed7/autospin/redaktion/library/Zend/Session.php
>   on line 462

I Use `Zend_Auth` and on my local server and it works well, but on a production server I get the preceding error, but not every time.

I have checked that `session.autostart` is set to `0` in the `.htaccess` file.

How do I fix this error?

---

Thank you for your Answer, but I do not user session_start() anywhere. Work only with ZF.

I Have this Problem only on shared server, on my local server script works perfectly.

I Use INIT Function with this code:

protected $user;

```
public function init()
{   
    if(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
    {
        $this->_redirect('auth/login');
    }else
    {
        $this->user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    }
}
```

I allready try to set tis code only in indexAction, so that other actions do not have to chack the Auth... but still have problems.

Ist there a way to set in an Action to do not check about session or somethink like this?

Beste regards

Comment: I get this error too sometimes... solution would be nice :)

Comment: I can think of two things that makes live- & dev-servers show different results: 1) not identical files; or 2) not identical configs

Comment: or different Server Settings....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's what it says it is. `Zend_Auth` tries to start a new session, since `Zend_Session::start()` has not yet been called.

The problem is that `Zend_Session::start()` has to be called before a session is started. But, since session.autostart is 0 (btw this is in *php.ini* not *.htaccess*), you have probably written `session_start();` somewhere. You're not allowed to do that, since ZF wishes to have full control over sessions, i.e. you shouldn't access the global session variable directly.

To solve it, search your code files for `session_start()` and either

1. remove all occurences but one. To notice if it's already been started, set `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);`
2. replace it with `Zend_Session::start();` at all places

If you can't find all occurrences, find the one session_start(); that bothers your `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()` and solve the problem quick n' dirty with the following snippet

```
try {
    Zend_Session::start();
} catch(Zend_Session_Exception $e) {
    session_start();
}
```

If you're using ZF in your whole application, I would go with 2)

Comment: I tryed this one 

  try {
      Zend_Session::start();
   if(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
      {
       $this->_redirect('auth/login');
      }else
      {
       $this->user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
      }
  } catch(Zend_Session_Exception $e) {
      session_start();
  }


and it works besset, but i still have problems, sometimes ith the requestes page empty...

Comment: Nice! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it helped you :) And remember, trust the stack trace, it's often your best friend ;)

Comment: it is a durty way to catch this arror, but it works and i am happy :)

Comment: FACEBOOK SDK HAS session_start()!

Comment: @max4ever: there's **no** reason for facebook to bundle Zend_Session if that's what you mean. Try `if(!session_id()) session_start();` in your code instead.

Comment: i just wanted to point out to other that facebook sdk might be the cause of the problem, facebook sdk already has if()... that but i was still getting errors until i changed it to Zend_Session::start()

Comment: @max4ever: I really think ZF is poorly designed in this matter and you are probably right. ZF should be more loosely coupled in this case. (You probably will have to redo your change every time you update your FB SDK.)

Comment: Please be aware that if you write this inside `init()` in `application/Bootstrap.php`, it does remove the error message, but this could cause the session incorrectly stored, it should be stored in `$_SESSION['__ZF']`, but any session saved from `Zend_Session_Namespace` won't be saved in there. Let's say you save and `'Auth'` session, zend will think that you did not save the session since it's not stored in `$_SESSION['__ZF']` which will cause you a headache why in the world you can't sign in.

Answer (score 21):

Before this drives you mad, there's probably nothing wrong with your code!

Check your application.ini for the session save path, for me it is 
APPLICATION_PATH '/session'

Now check you have the correct permissions!
If not then cd into the application folder and type

```
sudo chmod 777 session
sudo chown -R [usernamehere] session
sudo chgrp -R [usernamehere] session
```

Job Done!

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes when PHP can't write to a file/directory, the error it throws can be a little misleading. I've run into the issue you describe before.

Comment: "Um, it says there's a thunderstorm in Texas. What should we do???" "Don't panic, son. It actually just means my tire pressure is low."

Comment: The error is misleading. This put me on the right road, Thanks! make sure the session folder exists.

Comment: why in the world would you make it read/write/execute for everyone?

Comment: it happend on centos7 after php upgrade, it changed owner of default session path /var/lib/php/session so it wasn't writable anymore

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error. On local machine, everything worked fine. On server not.
My solution was to put `Zend_Session::start();` in the index.php before running bootstrap. So that it looks like this:

```
<?php
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';  

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV, 
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Zend_Session::start();

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 major reasons that produce this issue:

1. session.auto_start should be set to 0 or off. You can check it by placing phpinfo(); in any file and try to access it in browser, then search auto_start is it 0 or off. If not then set it off or 0.
2. Check session path session.save_path in configuration at server. If with default configuration it's displaying error 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()', set it to '/temp'
3. May be you have used session_start() in your code before zend session initialization.

In most cases the 2nd option is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing applications with the **RPCL** library (**RADPHP**) and you are getting this error:

> Application raised an exception class Zend_Session_Exception with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()',

then here is my solution.

You will be surprised how simple it is. Simple include the line

> require_once("zcommon.inc.php");

just after the opening PHP tag in the file containing **ZAuth** component – usually this is the file with a  **DataModule** form. Of course make sure the file ***zcommon.inc.php*** is in your path. This will ensure that the Zend session will start first instead of the RPCL session.

Also make sure the name of the php files in your application correspond to the name of the containing classes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to draw your attention to the garbage collection problem, solved here [Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder/2952173#2952173) or http://somethingemporium.com/2007/06/obscure-error-with-php5-on-debian-ubuntu-session-phpini-garbage.

After fixing the 'session has already been started' I encountered the GC bug. I suspect that the GC bug might be the root cause for the session bug at least in some instances. So far I have not had enough time to investigate thoroughly, but please comment if GC and session bug are related in your case as well.

Answer (score 3):

**There is an issue opened for this problem:**

[#25 "session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()" error message is misleading](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/25)

Answer (score 2):

had the same error. it occured only if two instances of the same session were used at the same time (e.g. two browser instances were loading at the same time). This is a result of php not being able to handle two open sessions with the same id at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

For those moving from one server to another.  Another issue can be user that apache runs under.  I was running a different user on my old box that was set on the new one. I used configs from my old httpd.conf, and forgot to update the permissions on /var/lib/php/session to reflect the different user.

To test, I changed the perms to 777. Everything worked fine, error was gone:

```
# cd /var/lib/php
# chmod 0777 session
```

So I returned the perms and changed the group. Of course change newApacheUser to the user account you are running httpd on IF NOT apache.

```
# chmod 0770 session
# chown root:newApacheUser session
```

Something to check out if your still having this issue:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()'

Answer (score 2):

In case this of any use, I cleared this error by taking out session related lines from my application/config/application.ini

```
;resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
;resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
;resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 3600
```

Thanks to [chelmertz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49879/chelmertz) for the insight into the cause of the problem.

Comment: That does not seem to be the core problem of the OP's issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be related to `session.save_path`. You can try `ini_set('session.save_path', 'path-to-your-session-storage-directory');`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and searching through all of the posts including this one I couldn't find an answer until I released that although I had the same exception result, my error was caused by something completely different.

I actually had an issue with autoloading.  Because of the problem during Bootstrap I believe this caused the exception above to be shown (hiding the real error).

So if you went through all of the other possible fixes, try commenting out the details in your Bootstrap and see if that gets you past this problem.  Obviously you slowly bring back the different parts of the bootstrap to uncover the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the page in a fresh incognito browser.

If it works, maybe it is a browser cache or cookie problem.

An error of this kind could probably appear after using different instances or installations of the same application, which is often the case during development or installation.