# Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder

Tags: php, session

I recently upgraded to PHP 5.3 and since then I get (sporadic) error messages which indicate Apache (or may be the cleaner of the session files) has no permissions to the folder where the sessions are stored.
This happens randomly and can't be reproduced with exact steps, which led me to guess it is the session cleaner.
Any one has any experience with such errors?

The error message (which is fired on the `session_start()` line) is:

> ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed:
>   Permission denied.

ls -ltr on the session directory gives:

```
drwx-wx-wt  2 root          root          4096 2010-05-25 12:39 php5
```

Inside this directory I do see session files owned by www-data which is my Apache, and the app does work fine. 
Which makes me wonder, under which user does the session GC runs?

Comment: I did, but not on 5.3. Turned out to be a permissions error that had filtered down to the session save path. I assume you've checked permissions?

Comment: @Jarrod I see www-data can read and write to that folder (which has w & r for everybody right now ,user,group and world) should I check something else?

Comment: I'm guessing the reason it happens sporadically is that the error occurs when the session garbage collector is run, which I think by default has a 1% chance of running per session initialization.

Have you made any changes to php.ini concerning sessions? What's outside the default here? Check the owner of the session folder, after that I'm at a loss without seeing the .ini or errors.

Comment: The owner is root, the sessions are created by www-data, everybody has access to this folder. I'll go over the ini settings one by one, look for something suspicious.

Comment: ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied (

Comment: @Itay Moav: "www-data can read and write to that folder" - does it have execute? And have you checked thats the webserver uid? Have you tried creating a file in that dir (or filesystem) as that uid?

Comment: no execute permissions, but it shouldn't have those. I see session files being created there correctly. www-data is the webserver user

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**The fix:** In your `php.ini` set `session.gc_probability` to `0`

**The cause**
I believe I found the answer here http://somethingemporium.com/2007/06/obscure-error-with-php5-on-debian-ubuntu-session-phpini-garbage

Essentially, the garbage collection is set up to be done by cron jobs on some systems (i.e. Ubuntu/Debian).  Some php ini executables like php-cli also try to do garbage collection and that results in the error you got.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 10.04 as well, but upon checking the php.ini I found `session.gc_probability` already set to `0`.

Comment: @Jonathan - You'll probably find that your application is setting the value then.

Comment: @SynackSA Oddly enough, it's when I create a custom, site specific php.ini file, that's when the `session.gc_probability` triggers to 1. This happened even when there are no settings in the php.ini file **whatsoever**! I'm running suphp on Ubuntu, Apache 2.2. I wonder if that is some type of bug. Anyway, adding `session.gc_probability = 0` to my custom, site specific php.ini file seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Jonathan That's the way it's suppose to work, as the default value is 1

Comment: This disables session garbage collection. You should probably want to check if there is actually a cron cleaning up your sessions.

Answer (score 23):

This seems to be a typical error on Ubuntu servers (I'm using Lucid LTS). The default permissions of the /var/lib/php5 directory there are

```
drwx-wx-wt  2 root     root     4096 2011-11-04 02:09 php5
```

so it can be written but not read by the web server, I guess that explains the errors.

As Ubuntu has it's own garbage cleaning via cron (`/etc/cron.d/php5`), it's probably best to disable php's garbage collection as suggested above by Diwant Vaidya.

```
session.gc_probability = 0
```

There's actually a reason the session folder should not be world readable - as the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) says:

> If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, such as /tmp (the
> default), other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by
> getting the list of files in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I currently use (which I am not sure is the correct one) is to give ownership on the session folder to the Apache user (www-data in my case).

Comment: As Marie mentions above, that can create a security issue for any production server.

Comment: I have long since implemented the right solution :-) But, the security issue is mostly in shared servers

Comment: @pike Session cleaning is handled by php cli via CRON

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been bugging me for a while.  I changed the value as suggested in php.ini and the issue kept occurring.  I found the same config value in my index.php and also private/Zend/session.php.  So it's worth looking a bit deeper if the issue keeps occurring.  I hope this is useful for someone.