# session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder)

I get this error sometimes, what gives?

I guess it has something do with file permissions on my ubuntu 10.10 box. How do I stop it?

Comment: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/565/garbage-collector-error-with-sessions-on-debian/p1

Comment: As currently that forum link given by @Agonych is not working I would like to propose a new answer, because maybe somebody else will need it. I like this solution [on another question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder/2952173#2952173) which works perfectly.