# Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session error

Tags: php, session

I am currently using Opencart 1.5.5.1 shopping cart software and have recently encountered an error. My sites frontpage has gone completely down and when I attempt to login via the admin side of the store I receive the following error:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_gbatrqu15lf22fbb0cprgjlrs5, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/vhosts/andysmotorcycles.com/httpdocs/system/library/session.php on line 11
```

I have checked line 11 and it is simply the `session_start()` command.

Comment: Do you have only webhosting or a real server / vserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder)

Comment: go to the /var/lib/php/ folder n give full permission to session folder

Comment: chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session fixed my problem after researching a little.

Comment: I know this question is very old, but for everyone coming to see this later: Performing a "chmod 777" without really understanding what you're doing can be a MAJOR security risk. That command allows anyone access to that folder. Do NOT run that command without being certain that that is really what you want to do. Thanks, Your Company's IT Security Department.

Comment: However, you need to change the owner of the sessions folder to www-data, to make it web-accessible. That will solve your issue and create 0 security issues.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though that you have used up all your inodes on your hosting plan (1 inode = 1 file) Most Hosting services limit the number of files that can be generated on the server (this includes everything (emails, source files, session files ...))  You most likely need to remove old session files from the var/lib/php/session dir. Once you do that, yur inodes usage will be uch and lower and your issue will be resolved. Try to use a cron to automatically scan the dir at a preset schedule and remove old session files