# Session set in subfolder not working on root folder in live server but works on localhost

Tags: php, session

This is driving me nuts. The code works fine on localhost but not on live server.

I set the session in subfolder, This is my subfolder file, I set a session using PHP:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'hi';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

But I can't access the session i set in subfolder, in root index using in index:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

On local the session variable test works fine, but on live server it never works. it is empty.

The code is same, and i am using session_start() on top of both pages.

Can someone tell me what is possible for this? I've been trying so many hours! Is there  aserver config that can cause this?

Comment: Try `echo $_SESSION['test'];` in the subfolder instead.

Comment: It works, but I need to use the session I registered in subfolder, into the root too!

Comment: Do you not get any error messages when you write to session? Is the live server is configured to display error messages?

Comment: @user2780294 I am not asking you to set the session, but to get using the session name in the index. What you are telling it to print is the session array, instead of just a session value in the array, accessed by index.

Comment: Possible place of reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder?rq=1

Comment: No error message, error reporting is set to All.