# $.POST call php page over 2000 times

Tags: javascript, php, session, post

I tried to call PHP page and it worked fine!
PHP page is in a PHP session.
I call the page about 2500 times.

But I have one problem: randomly the page generate a error:

> session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(C:\Windows\temp)
>   failed: No error (0)

**Javascript:**

```
var vet = <?=json_encode($array)?>;
var ct = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
   filter(vet[ct]);
});

function filter(report)
{
   $.post('handlers/export.php', {
      action: action,
      report: report
      }, function(updates) {
         values = JSON.parse(updateRecords);
         console.log(values);
      });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3600); //60 minuti
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 3600); //60 minuti
set_time_limit (3600); //60 minuti

//VERIFICHE prima di caricare la pagina (richiesta)
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
   session_start();

...
?>
```

I have tried this solution: [Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder)

> The fix: In your php.ini set session.gc_probability to 0

but the problem perist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with PHP 5.3 and sessions folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder)

Comment: I have tried this solution, but the problem perist

Comment: Why so many posts?  Make 1 and parse it correctly on the server instead.

Comment: Because, I need to complete data(table) one by one(row by row). Could you have  another solution? Thank you