# Zend_Auth and Zend_Namespace Session Error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session

I'm developing an application, everything works fine but sometimes i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Session.php:462 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true) #1 /var/vhosts/rmanager.vsnetwork.net/application/views/helpers/GetProjetoNome.php(7): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('rmanager') #2 [internal function]: Zend_View_Helper_GetProjetoNome->GetProjetoNome() #3 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 /var/vhosts/rmanager.vsnetwork.net/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(73): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('GetProjetoNome', Array) #5 /var/vhosts/rmanager.vsnetwork.net/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(73): Zend_View->GetProjetoNome() #6 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/View.php(108): include('/var/vhosts/rma...') #7 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(880) in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Session.php on line 462
```

If i refresh the page, it works.

Sometimes it returns me the error while i send post to the same page

I'm using Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl inside a plugin and Zend_Namespace in various places of my application.

Does anyone has idea why it is happing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda hard to help you with so little information, but as far as i read ealier this week when i play with session_namespace, you have to be very careful with it.

[This paragraph has been very helpful for me](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.headers_sent)

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever start the session explicitly. Just use it automatically. I also use Zend_Auth and Zend_Sesison_Namespace many times but that error never comes.

Comment: Yes, I don't start it explicitly. I just use Zend_Auth and Zend_Sesison_Namespace and i let zendframework start it automatically

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418124/zend-framework-problem